Hiding Sheets Upon Workbook Activation
I found this code on the net, and supposedly it works, and you would have to do a loop to unhide them, but I'm trying to hide them. So, why doesn't this work. And, do I just drop the dimensions of the Listboxes in willy-nilly, or do they need a With Statement or something?
I've tried everything I can think of
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    
    Worksheets(Array("Data", "CLLIDATA", "OXXXXS", "LXXXXXXB", "LXXXXXXT", "BXXXXXXO", _
        "LXXXXXXO", "NXXXXXXV", "NXXXXXX1", "JXXXXXXX", "NXXXXXXP", "LXXXXXXB-LXXXXXXT MAP", _
        "LXXXXXXB-BXXXXXXO MAP", "LXXXXXXB-LXXXXXXO MAP")).Visible = False
                
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Index").ListBox1
        .Clear
        .List = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("F1:F15").Value
    End With
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Index").ListBox2
        .Clear
        .List = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("D1:D8").Value
    End With
                            
    Sheets("Index").ListBox1.Height = 141
    Sheets("Index").ListBox1.Left = 333.5
    Sheets("Index").ListBox1.Top = 102
    Sheets("Index").ListBox1.Width = 195.5
    
    Sheets("Index").ListBox2.Height = 144
    Sheets("Index").ListBox2.Left = 128.5
    Sheets("Index").ListBox2.Top = 20
    Sheets("Index").ListBox2.Width = 82.5
    
    Sheets("Index").ListBox3.Height = 152
    Sheets("Index").ListBox3.Left = 650
    Sheets("Index").ListBox3.Top = 20
    Sheets("Index").ListBox3.Width = 87.5
    
    Sheets("Index").ToggleButton1.Height = 28.5
    Sheets("Index").ToggleButton1.Left = 384.5
    Sheets("Index").ToggleButton1.Top = 17.5
    Sheets("Index").ToggleButton1.Width = 93.5
    
    Sheets("Index").TextBox1.Height = 29
    Sheets("Index").TextBox1.Left = 361
    Sheets("Index").TextBox1.Top = 60
    Sheets("Index").TextBox1.Width = 140.5
                            
End Sub


What's your expected output?

Are the same names in Data!F1:F15?

By trial and error, I have concluded that all sheets must exist and be visible to be hidden at once. It doesn't work for xlSheetVeryHidden or the other way around i.e. you cannot make them visible at once. IMO, a loop is mandatory either way.

If there are charts among the sheets, you need to use the Sheets collection i.e. instead of Worksheets use Sheets. If this is the case, and you decide to loop, don't forget to declare the sheet variable As Object since there is no Sheet object in VBA.

I created a subroutine specifically to set the visibility of the sheets array.  This is preferable because we can test it independently of the main code.  We can also unhide the same group of sheets if we like.

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        
    SetVisibility_ArrayOfWorksheet xlSheetHidden
                    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Index").ListBox1
        .Clear
        .List = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("F1:F15").Value
    End With
        
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Index").ListBox2
        .Clear
        .List = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("D1:D8").Value
    End With
                                
    Sheets("Index").ListBox1.Height = 141
    Sheets("Index").ListBox1.Left = 333.5
    Sheets("Index").ListBox1.Top = 102
    Sheets("Index").ListBox1.Width = 195.5
        
    Sheets("Index").ListBox2.Height = 144
    Sheets("Index").ListBox2.Left = 128.5
    Sheets("Index").ListBox2.Top = 20
    Sheets("Index").ListBox2.Width = 82.5
        
    Sheets("Index").ListBox3.Height = 152
    Sheets("Index").ListBox3.Left = 650
    Sheets("Index").ListBox3.Top = 20
    Sheets("Index").ListBox3.Width = 87.5
        
    Sheets("Index").ToggleButton1.Height = 28.5
    Sheets("Index").ToggleButton1.Left = 384.5
    Sheets("Index").ToggleButton1.Top = 17.5
    Sheets("Index").ToggleButton1.Width = 93.5
        
    Sheets("Index").TextBox1.Height = 29
    Sheets("Index").TextBox1.Left = 361
    Sheets("Index").TextBox1.Top = 60
    Sheets("Index").TextBox1.Width = 140.5
                                
End Sub

In a public module:
Sub SetVisibility_ArrayOfWorksheet(Visible As XlSheetVisibility)
    ' Declare a variable to hold the target worksheets
    Dim TargetWorksheets As Sheets
    
    ' Set the target worksheets to an array of sheet names
    ' The array contains the names of multiple worksheets that need visibility changes
    Set TargetWorksheets = Worksheets(Array("Data", "CLLIDATA", "OXXXXS", _
        "LXXXXXXB", "LXXXXXXT", "BXXXXXXO", "LXXXXXXO", "NXXXXXXV", "NXXXXXX1", _
        "JXXXXXXX", "NXXXXXXP", "LXXXXXXB-LXXXXXXT MAP", _
        "LXXXXXXB-BXXXXXXO MAP", "LXXXXXXB-LXXXXXXO MAP"))
    
    ' Declare a variable to iterate over each worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    ' Loop through each worksheet in the TargetWorksheets collection
    For Each ws In TargetWorksheets
        ' Set the visibility of each worksheet to the value provided (Visible)
        ' Visible can be xlSheetVisible, xlSheetHidden, or xlSheetVeryHidden
        ws.Visible = Visible
    Next
End Sub


I couldn't get your method to work for some reason. I got this to work:
           Dim sheetNamesToHide As Variant
        sheetNamesToHide = Array("Data", "CXXXXXXA", "OXXXXXXS", "LXXXXXXB", "LXXXXXXT", _
        "BXXXXXXO", "LXXXXXXO", "NXXXXXXV", "NXXXXXX1", "JXXXXXXX", "NXXXXXXP", _
        "LXXXXXXB-LXXXXXXT MAP", "LXXXXXXB-BXXXXXXO MAP", "LXXXXXXB-LXXXXXXO MAP")
            For Each Loop
                'Check if the sheet name is in the list to hide
            If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, sheetNamesToHide, 0)) Then
             'Sheet names not found in the list, so not hidden
            Else
                ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            End If

